# Audacity Waveform Limiting Amplitude

Tags: piano, audacity

I'm trying to record my keyboard with Audacity, but I get the following waveform.

[image: 1]]

Notice that the amplitude of the wave seems to be limited. I'm sure there's an easy fix to this, but I couldn't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does it sound ok or is the sound messed up also?

Comment: @ToddWilcox the sound is fuzzy.

Comment: What equipment are you using? What audio interface? What cables?

Comment: I think it is clipping somewhere in your audio chain. How are you recording? Can you also post a link so we can listen to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is most definitely not Audacity's fault.  It only displays what some A/D converter is feeding it.  If you're using a microphone input on your computer, try turning down the input gain. Ditto if something else is doing the digitization.